# Identifing monitor DC power connector

Tags: power-supply, connector

[image: male and dc power connector]

I can't measure it precisely but as far as I can tell male has **6 mm outer diameter, around 4 mm inner diameter and center pin probably 1 mm or so**. It's the power cord of an LG monitor. I think it's LG Flatron 22EN33 but I'm not sure.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff All I'm asking is if someone knows the type of connector of similar measures that might be a match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely an EIAJ connector. Which one I can't say just based on your approximate data, but from [this catalog](http://www.wes.com.au/mediapub/ebook/wescat2014np/files/assets/basic-html/index.html#231):

An EIAJ-05 has 4.4 x 6.5 x 1.4

An EIAJ-04 has 3.4 x 5.5 x 1.0

These are inner-barrel diameter, outer-barrel diameter and pin diameter for the "male" plug; all in mm.

By the way, these are somewhat colloquial names. The correct/official one is JEITA RC-5320A connector. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIAJ_connector Note that the lead image there may be misleading as the EIAJ-01 to -03 don't have the pin in the male.

Of course it could be something custom instead. LG is big enough to order something like that.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it's an EIAJ-05. I've managed to find some LG AC/DC adapters with same or similar rating and they're all 6.5 mm x 4.4mm.  I'll order some of those and see if they  fit.

Comment: Could you please update this answer / comment with whether or not the EIAJ-05 was the correct fit, and what the exact model of the monitor was?

Comment: I found MJ-085N and MP-205 as male / female counterparts for EIAJ-05, would these work? I see they are rated for 2A only, while the monitor power supply output is declared for up to 5.79A, did LG use these same connectors or something rated for higher current?

Comment: @andrean: must be some big whooping monitor to consume 120W, because the usual voltage is 19V for those and most supplies for them don't deliver more than 2A. You could probably measure the current with a clampmeter etc.

Comment: I haven't measured tbh, just looked at what the power brick sticker has written on it (it says 19V / 5.79A). While on the back of the monitor it's 19V / 5A written. Do you think it would not draw such a high current despite these specs? (it's an LG 27" OLED monitor 27GP95R) - well most importantly, what do you think about the two connectors I mentioned?